# Bootstrap 3 modal slideshow

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, swiper.js

i have problem regarding bootstrap 3 with modal that has slideshow (Swiper) inside. When i put it on modal it isn't working but when i put it on clasic page it is working.

I have tried to use shown.bs.modal with mySwiper.update() and no luck.

Can somebody help me ?

Answer (score 0):

this is solution to my problem

```
 $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        mySwiper.update();
    });
```